# how i extends my custom order item using WC_Order_Item_Product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

i want to extends my custom entity from WC_Order_Item_Product. i add my custom extra data to this class .

```
class RoomOrderItem extends OrderItemLegacy {

    protected $extra_data = array(
        'product_id' => 0,
        'variation_id' => 0,
        'quantity' => 1,
        'tax_class'=> '', 
        'subtotal' => 0,
        'subtotal_tax' => 0,
        'total' => 0,
        'total_tax' => 0,
        'taxes' => [
            'subtotal' => [], 
            'total' => [], 
        ],  
        'period' => '', 
        'extra' => '', 
        'manager' => [], 
        'entity' => __CLASS__,
    );  

    public function set_period(DateTime $day){
        $this->set_prop('period',$day->format('Y-m-d'));
        return $this;
    }   

    public function set_extra(int $extra){
        $this->set_prop('extra',$extra);
        return $this;
    }   

    public function set_manager(array $manager){
        $this->set_prop('manager',$manager);
        return $this;
    }   

}
```

but when is adding my custom order item (RoomOrderItem extends WC_Order_Item_Product) new extra data does not save in any tables. here is my sample code for adding new RoomOrdeItem to order object:

```
    public function add(RoomCartItem $room_cart_item){
        $this->set_props([
            'quantity'     => $room_cart_item->get_prop('quantity'),
            'variation'    => $room_cart_item->get_prop('variation'),
            'subtotal'     => $room_cart_item->get_prop('line_subtotal'),
            'total'        => $room_cart_item->get_prop('line_total'),
            'name'         => $room_cart_item->get_hotel()->get_name(),
            'product_id'   => $room_cart_item->get_prop('product_id'),
            'variation_id' => $room_cart_item->get_prop('variation_id'),
            '_period'      => $room_cart_item->get_period(),
            '_manager'     => $room_cart_item->get_manager(),
            '_extra'       => $room_cart_item->get_extra(),
            '_entity'      => __CLASS__,
        ]);
        return $this->get_order()->add_item($this);
    }
```

In addition, I know that a meta can be added to this item with the $this->add_meta_data(). But why the new data is not automatically saved in the item.

Answer (score 0):

I think your issues is you haven't saved the data.

if you're working with an orderitem object class you should be able to use the `save()` function.

```
public function add(RoomCartItem $room_cart_item){
    $this->set_props([
        'quantity'     => $room_cart_item->get_prop('quantity'),
        'variation'    => $room_cart_item->get_prop('variation'),
        'subtotal'     => $room_cart_item->get_prop('line_subtotal'),
        'total'        => $room_cart_item->get_prop('line_total'),
        'name'         => $room_cart_item->get_hotel()->get_name(),
        'product_id'   => $room_cart_item->get_prop('product_id'),
        'variation_id' => $room_cart_item->get_prop('variation_id'),
        '_period'      => $room_cart_item->get_period(),
        '_manager'     => $room_cart_item->get_manager(),
        '_extra'       => $room_cart_item->get_extra(),
        '_entity'      => __CLASS__,
    ]);
    $this->save(); //save the updated props
    return $this->get_order()->add_item($this);
}
```

Comment: thank you for your replay. i want to save all props at end of program process (end of request) just like WC_Data automaticlly.